# Conditional statement in daa.R of the R "matchingMarkets" library

Tags: r, conditional-statements, parentheses

I am trying to get my head around [daa.R](https://github.com/thiloklein/matchingMarkets/blob/master/R/daa.R), one of the functions in the [matchingMarkets](https://github.com/thiloklein/matchingMarkets) R library (links are to GitHub repositories). On lines 134-135, one finds the following `if` statement

```
if (0 %in% (c.hist[[j]] & any(c.prefs[ ,j]==proposers[k]))){  # if no history and proposer is on preference list
          c.hist[[j]][c.hist[[j]]==0][1] <- proposers[k]              # then accept
}
```

where `c.hist` and `proposers` are a list and `c.prefs` a matrix.

I am puzzled by the parentheses in the conditional statement. Instead of the above synthax, I would have opted for

```
if (0 %in% c.hist[[j]] & any(c.prefs[ ,j]==proposers[k]))
```

I don't understand how the original condition may work. How could R possibly check whether 0 is in `(c.hist[[j]] & any(c.prefs[ ,j]==proposers[k]))`?

I am a beginner in R, so I wanted to make sure I was not missing something and tried to replicate a similar synthax with other conditions such as,

```
> x = list(4,3)
> y = list(5,2)
> if (3 %in% (x & any(y == 5))){z = 8}
```

As I expected, I got an error message

```
 Error in x & any(y == 5) : operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

whereas things go just fine when I write

```
if (3 %in% x & any(y == 5)){z = 8}
```

instead.

What am I missing? Why would the kind of conditional synthax I am puzzled by work in daa.R and not with the other conditions I tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask R if `0 %in% x` where `x` is a logical vector, R will first convert `x` to a numeric vector  where `FALSE` becomes `0` and `TRUE` becomes `1`. So essentially, asking if `0 %in% x` is like asking if `x` contains any `FALSE`. This is arguably pretty bad practice. A better approach would be to test if `any(!x)` or `!all(x)`. Worse, if `x` has length `1` as it seems to be the case here, you would just test if `!x`.

In light of the contorted usage, you are raising a very good question: is the code doing what it really meant to do? In R, the `%in%` operator has higher precedence than `&` (see `?Syntax`), thus these two statements are not the same:

```
0 %in% (c.hist[[j]]) & any(c.prefs[ ,j]==proposers[k]))   # original code

0 %in% c.hist[[j]] & any(c.prefs[ ,j]==proposers[k])      # what you suggested
```

and we would need to look closely at what the code is supposed to be doing to decide if it is correct or wrong. I will just point out that you did not test your assumption properly: the error you got ("unexpected '{'") is because you forgot a closing parenthesis:

```
if (3 %in% (x & any(y == 5)){z = 8}
```

should be

```
if (3 %in% (x & any(y == 5))){z = 8}
```

Comment: Cool, but I fear you are disfiguring your question a bit. Now I have to answer a completely new question... The error you get is because `&` does not accept a list (`x`) in `x & any(y == 5)`. Note that the original code uses `c.hist[[j]]` in place of `x` and my guess is that `c.hist[[j]]` is a numeric vector.

Comment: many thanks for pointing that out, interesting points and definitely right on the parentheses issue in my attempt to check the synthax in other contexts. I will correct it in the original question. As you suggested, this does not get to the core of the problem, but I think it gets us a much more sensible error message

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I could recover the previous version and mention the edit more clearly as an edit. I wanted to make the edit clear initially, but have been told on some SE site that it is bad practice and that if one wants to edit a question, one should not leave any trace of the old version. Not sure about the standards on Stackoverflow...

Comment: Oh and thanks for following up on the question, I think I am starting to understand what's going on. Indeed, `c.hist[[j]]` is a numerical vector in the initial code. Based on my understanding of the rest of the code, the trick does work, and the code does what it is meant to do, although in the rather peculiar way you described in the answer.